# How do I use OAuth 2.0 with discord and can I do so without PHP?

Tags: javascript, html, oauth-2.0, discord

I’m creating a website using HTML for my friends, and I decided that logging in with Discord would be the easiest way to have a login system as we all use it. I read the documentation for Discord OAuth2, yet I can’t understand how I would go about implementing a Discord login to a website made with HTML. I would prefer if I didn’t have to use PHP, as I know almost nothing about it.

Comment: OAuth 2.0 would require some sort of server side code, doesn't have to be PHPee

Comment: Then again, "login system" also implies server-side code. There is no meaning to "logging in" if you have a static site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really not possible to implement a login functionality without using a programming language. You would need a way to make API calls to discord so that it can verify the user but this isn't possible with a plain HTML and CSS website.

I would suggest you learn a language like Javascript which will enable you to efficiently interact with the Discord API

Comment: Still, adding sign-in functionality to a plain HTML and JS website doesn't really give you much. One thing I can think of is to add a "Welcome Ian" message after you log in. You can't secure any information if all of it lives in your HTML and JS files.

Comment: So some kind of database is also needed to persist the data don't you think. I find it also interesting that a few weeks ago I was learning implementing login functionality in flask and I had a "Welcome Ian" page :)